# spring batch API to dynamically create tasks and steps

Tags: api, dynamic, task, spring-batch

Our application allows the users to dynamically assemble/construct Tasks and steps ( Remote calls to various services). Once the user has defined/constructed a Task with various Steps, the system will allow the Task to be run manually or scheduled.

To implement above functionality, what would it take to use spring batch for programmatically create a given Task and its constituent Steps ? I'm assuming that such tasks can be scheduled with the help of Quartz, etc.

I understand that spring XD and spring cloud watch incorporate similar features -- some pointers to the relevant XD codebase/examples(or any other project codebase) which would help in my task would help.

What considerations should I keep in mind ? Any gotchas ?

Currently not using any cloud platform but the next version will be deployed to a cloud platform.

Thanks very much.

Comment: interesting question. I will be motivated to investigate it if it provides enough bounties

Comment: Hi @KenChan : I'm willing to do the same. The question gets eligible for bounties in 23 hours from now. I will place a decent bounty on the same.

Comment: Hi @KenChan, added a bounty of 150 points.

Comment: @Ken Chan Investigate or answer?

Comment: @KenChan :  I put up 150 points based on your request and now about 13 hours or so before the bounty expires. Please answer or atleast respond on where things are at.

Comment: I am relaxing in my long holiday and do not have time to investigate. Also I did not request you must place a bounty for me or I must commit to provide the solutions. I just express my thought that it is an interesting question and I will be motivated if it provides 'enough' bounty (and actually 150 is not enough to motivate me consider the time I expect to spend)

Comment: Anyways, I would try to use the `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` to programmatically build a job and its step first , then explore the options to programmtically register these instances as a spring bean which you could easily find a lot of infomration from the internet for how to do it.Cheers.

Comment: @KenChan : How much bounty were you expecting ? Please let me know and I consider your request. Thank you.